# How to remove semicolon from xml in XSLT

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have an xml and xslt..

I need to remove semicolon from my xml and display in webpage.

I cannot give the position as 1 or 2,because it may vary..

**My xslt**

```
<xsl:variable name="link" select="Hotel/@thumb" />
<img src="{substring($link, 1, string-length($link) - 1)}"/>
```

**XML**

```
 http://static.ezeego1.co.in/ezeego1/images/hotelimages/ezimages/ezthumbimg/80760_conference_hall.jpg;
```

Any help please..

Comment: What you show as xml is not xml. Can you describe how is structured your xml, and if possible how it is generated?

Comment: I will make it clear..In my xml i have the above url.Using my xslt, I just want to remove the semicolon and want to have the remaining text..I hope you understood.

Comment: you couuld try with the "translate" function. Best regars, PEter

Comment: write out what you want as output. removing the : is easy with translate($link,':','') but I do not think that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that Kevin Brown,It worked..